# Find set of maximal rectangular area spaces in a rectangle of 0 and 1s

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a matrix of 0 and 1's and I am trying to find the set of maximal rectangle areas in that. For instance in following matrix A:

```
array([
   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

The answer should be:

```
A[0:8, 6:9]
A[0:4, 3:9]
A[0, 0:9]
A[7, 5:9]
```

I tried to solve the problem by sequentially applying the [maximal rectangle area problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximal-rectangle/)

But i could not come up with a rule to remove the maximal rectangle, but do not remove the next maximal rectangle that works in all settings!
It might not be the most descent idea, so I appreciate if there is a better approach to this problem!

Comment: Your link doesn't add anything to the explanation: it merely poses a sub-problem, with no solution.

Comment: Why is your given solution the correct one?  You seem to require some partial overlap of rectangles; removing a found rectangle isn't how your problem works.  In particular, why is the last column not allowed for any rectangle but the first?

Comment: That problem is well known and has many solutions like [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-size-sub-matrix-with-all-1s-in-a-binary-matrix/).

Comment: @Prune I changed the solution. I wrote it not correctly at first.

Comment: If the problem has many solutions, then where is your coding attempt, and what is the problem with it?

Comment: I do not code something that is wrong. My question is algorithmic and more about how to approach the problem and if my approach can be modified in anyway to work. I have not coded it since i am missing the part about how to remove the maximal rectangular area such that it does not remove the other candidates! @Prune.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195710/discussion-between-prune-and-ebramos).

Comment: What do you mean by Maximal rectangle area? Should be a rectangle with elements as 1's or can it have both 0's and 1's in it? Please clear that.

Comment: Also, your answer stated is not clear as well. Please clarify that or give link where the exact problem is mentioned.

Comment: I don't understand your example answer. Could you (or someone) please explain what `A[0:8, 6:9]` means, for example?

Comment: @CodeHunter It can just include ones.